# How to override Django's signal handler?

Tags: python, django, satchmo

in a Django shop application there gets registered signal handler to some action like adding an item to the cart.

I'd like to replace this handler with my own version in `localsite/models.py`, ie. without touching original sources.

If just calling `connect` method

```
signals.satchmo_cart_add_verify.connect(my_veto_out_of_stock)
```

the custom handler appends to the list of current recievers and the original still gets an action:

```
print signals.satchmo_cart_add_verify.receivers
"""
[((140073113515864, 140073319632416), <weakref at 0x7f65502c1aa0;
to 'function' at 0x7f65502c7758 (veto_out_of_stock)>),
((140073114981632, 140073319632416), <weakref at 0x7f65504295d0;
to 'function' at 0x7f655042d500 (my_veto_out_of_stock)>)]
"""
```

I can in an advance remove the original handlers with

```
for hnd in signals.satchmo_cart_add_verify.receivers:
    del hnd
```

but find it ugly and hackish.

So what's the proper way to replace the signal handler ?

Thanks

Comment: I've just found one way. Importing the original handler function and passing it to `signals..disconnect` but is there some more generic way even when importing the original function is not possible ?

Comment: well, just typing the link...

Comment: If you cannot import the original function (because you don't know where it is when programming?), you could get the receiver func by something like `signals.satchmo_cart_add_verify.receivers[0][1]()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your tried [`Signal.disconnect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#disconnecting-signals)?

```
signals.satchmo_cart_add_verify.disconnect(
    signals.satchmo_cart_add_verify.receivers[0][1]())
```

This way is clear IMO.

Comment: If nobody else would complain about *clarity* of this solution, I'm going to accept this answer.